# Subsection are unnumbered in text and toc

Tags: sectioning, templates

I have searched through the website but could not find out a reason for this. My subsections are unnumbered in the text and the table of cotents. I got this template from my university (Brazilian) and could not find the mistake. I'm still learning, I imagine it should be  simple to solve. Could anyone help?

https://www.sharelatex.com/project/591007db6f094cf75b363c34

Comment: welcome, subsections and subsubsections are unnumbered for *Universidade Tecnológica Federal do Paraná*

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work", "not accepting"? Are you referring to the (lack of) numbering that Johannes mentions?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, i'm reffering to the lack of numbering and it not beeing listed at the \tableofcontents. I would like to "\sebsection{Objetivo Geral}"  appear as 1.4.1 in the text and in the table of contents as well. And \subsubsubsection{teste} appears as 1.5.1.1

Comment: I got it! What I did as removing the lines:
\setsecnumdepth{section}
and
\settocdepth{section}

Thank you guys

Answer (score 2):

Scientific reports at *Universidade Tecnológica Federal do Paraná* have unnumbered subsections. The template sets it that way. If you want to override university guidelines, add the lines

```
\settocdepth{subsection}
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
```

to your main tex file.

---

[Sharelatex has a template](https://de.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/utfpr-thesis) for UTFPR.
[Overleaf has a template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/utfpr-tcc-template/ypmhjndztmtb#.WRFT5TQlH4g) for UTFPR.
Both of them seem to be provided for the same purpose, both of them show subsections numbered and in the table of contents.

Why there are so many different templates for one university, i don't have a clue.

---

Off topic: you have a serious issue with `\\` at the end of lines. You even get errors from it. Rule of thumb: Unless inside a tabular environment, `\\` are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

To show subsection numbering at the text and table of contents, I removed the lines:
\settocdepth{section}
\settocdepth{section}

Comment: If this is about changing the file `lames-tex.sty`, bad idea. You don't own the file, you don't have copyright and if you don't rename the file, you get into license issues.